# VS Code style-lint ignore directories

Tags: visual-studio-code, lint, stylelint

Is it possible to ignore my CSS path, beacuse I only use **[stylelint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shinnn.stylelint)** for SCSS validation?

e.g. - I have the following structure:

```
assets/
    css/
    scss/
```

How can I disable the `css/` folder from being indexed, trough the settings.json file of VSCode?

I found **[this in the docs](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configuration/#ignorefiles)**, but I don't know how to implement it in VSCode.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're using the VS Code stylelint extension, you can specify ignore paths via the `stylelint.configOverrides` setting.

Add the following to your VS Code settings.json file:

```
"stylelint.configOverrides": {
    "ignoreFiles": "assets/css/**"
}
```

Alternatively you can add a `.stylelintignore` file to the root folder of your project and add the ignore paths there:

```
assets/css/**
```

Comment: For anyone who reaches here, `stylelint.configOverrides` is not deprecated. However there is a PR to support `ignoreFilePath`.

Comment: ^ IS NOW DEPRECATED* :)

Answer (score 7):

I'm using stylelint@9.2.0 with vscode-stylelint@0.20.4, and for me the .stylelintignore file is not being respected. If i use the CLI it is respected but the vscode plugin does not seem to do this correctly.

Comment: I found that it seemed like my `.stylelintrc.js` was not being respected, even if I restarted VSCode, the ignored files still showed errors. However I had to change the ignored files, and then save them (saving without modifying them didn't work) and then it seemed to pickup they were ignored and all the errors went away. Something a little odd going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Jack Russell, I found that the VS Code stylelint plugin currently seems to ignore the .stylelintignore file.

To get around this limitation, I removed the .stylelintignore entirely and moved its settings into .stylelintrc instead. I.e. from something like this in .stylelintignore:

```
ignorethisfolder/**/*
path/to/ignorethisfile.css
```

To something like this in .stylelintrc:

```json
  "ignoreFiles": [
    "ignorethisfolder/**/*",
    "path/to/ignorethisfile.css",
  ]
```