# How do I exclude files from css lint in vscode

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

VS Code seems to have a built in CSS linter, which is great. But there's a lot of code that I don't want to lint, as shown in the below screenshot. How do I exclude certain directories from being linted?

[image: unwanted errors]

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
{ 
   "css.validate": false 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, VS Code's built-in linter doesn't have an exclusion setting. You can only disable specific rules (see `css.` properties in settings.json).

You could try using the [stylelint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shinnn.stylelint) extension with the `ignoreFiles` setting (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42100925/5990435)) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use:

```json
{
  "css.lint.unknownProperties": "ignore"
}
```

In my `settings.json`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to exclude  the folder in */.vscode/settings.json like this:

```
{
"files.exclude": {
  "**/app/**/*.js.map": true,
  "**/app/**/*.js": true,
  "**/node_modules/**": true
}
```

Comment: This a good approach, but this won't work if I want to take a look at the source code of a library.